# How can I debug a series of piped commands in zsh?

Tags: mac, macbook-pro, zsh

The command

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep \"EDID\" | sed "/[^<]*</s///" | xxd -p -r | strings -6
```

is not giving any result. Can any one help.

I got [this command](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4034848?start=4080&tstart=0) from an article that maintains (I paraphrase) *that rMBP can have Samsung / LG screens,  and that the LG screens are all defective.*

My MacBook Pro retina 13" so I naturally wanted to check the details of my hardware. Mine is zsh

Comment: Your question could use some work. Please clarify what you are trying to accomplish instead of just linking to an external site.

Comment: The command in the linked article is different than the one you've included above.

Comment: @patrix They command is having some escape characters issue with SO's escaping characters.

Comment: As your question is more about the non-working shell pipeline than the Retina topic, I've changed the title accordingly.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `ioreg -lw0 | grep \"EDID\"` to the question?

Answer (score 3):

One way to debug command-line pipes is to insert `| tee debug.txt` between two steps and look at the file `debug.txt` to check whether the previous steps are correct.

Comment: This is a great way to debug things. In your case, you want to grep for `IODisplayEDID` as opposed to `\"EDID\"` so that you get the string output from the ioreg input.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to debug pipes is to add each element in sequence until you have a problem. For example, start with

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep \"EDID\"
```

which outputs nothing. That means there is no string `"EDID"` output by ioreg. So there's the problem.

But hey, I don't like seeing a problem unsolved: let's simplify a little more by getting rid of the quotation marks. I assume your Mac is like mine.

```
ioreg -lw0 | grep EDID
```

matches a string `IODisplayEDID`. Substituting `IODisplayEDID` for `EDID` in the `grep` argument succeeds. Don't forget to "escape" the quotes with a backslash (or, in this case, you can omit the quotes and get the same result).